# Program doesn't output all 3 numbers

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that's supposed to take 3 numbers and output them with a cubed value and it's only displaying the first number.

```
startrange = input ("input first number  ") #asks for numbers 
endrange = input ("input second number  ")
increment = input ("input thrid number  ")
    
for x in range(int(startrange), int(endrange), int(increment)):  
    print(x, "let me show you the cubbed version", x*x*x) #calculates and prints
```

Comment: endrange is exclusive. What is your input, what is the expected output? Ideally please provide a [mre] which does not need user input. You can do that by copying your project and replacing the input by hard coded values

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In order to help us better understand, please [edit] to include a [mcve] showing what you are passing in as inputs and your expected output

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. On inputting `1`, `6` and `1`, I got all cubes of 1 to 5...

Comment: What does "cubbed" mean?

Comment: This question is incomplete. You need to include a test - input values, expected result and actual result. Your code seems correct. What do you see that's different?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are providing bigger increment value that's is why it is printing cube of only one value. Example below
[image]

Secondly keep in mind that end range is exculsive for example if you put end range is 5 to include 5 you need to add 1 in variable

```
 startrange = input ("input first number  ") #asks for numbers 
 endrange = input ("input second number  ")
 increment = input ("input thrid number  ")
 for x in range(int(startrange), int(endrange)+1, int(increment)):  
      print(x, "let me show you the cubbed version", x*x*x)
```

End Range is exculsive if you want to include end range you can do `int(endrange)+1` it will include end range. Third input is increment and in loop it will move steps according to value of increment if you put 2 it will increment loop by value of 2 not 1

Output:

```
input first number  1
input second number  5
input thrid number  1
1 let me show you the cubbed version 1
2 let me show you the cubbed version 8
3 let me show you the cubbed version 27
4 let me show you the cubbed version 64
5 let me show you the cubbed version 125
```